# optimized code for deleting a node in singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

can this piece of code be used to delete a node at a specified position

```
void del(node *&head,int position)
{
        int jump=0;
        node *temp=head;
        while(jump<position-1)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            jump++;
        }
        node *copy=temp->next;
        temp->next=temp->next->next;
        delete copy;
```

also what is the most efficient method to delete a node in a specific position?

Comment: This is efficient, but it lacks error checking. What if `position` is greater than the size of your list? What if it is `0`?

Comment: When you ask, can this piece of code delete the node? First thing, is it working or are you having any errors. You tell us.

Comment: Next thing you are missing edge cases like first and last element deletion, needs some extra care.

Comment: The shown code is fundamentally flawed, and will not work. As far as "most efficient" goes, can you explain what "most efficient" mean to you?

Comment: @JitendraYadav it is working and I have covered the corner cases. I just wanted to makes sure if there are any flaws in this part which deletes the node at any other given position than corner cases.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I have done checks on corner cases and it seems to work fine. I just wanted to make sure if there are any flaws in this part where I have delete the node at any other position than corner cases

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it would be a great help if you could tell me what the flaws are, I'm totally new to this. By "most efficient" what I meant to ask was  if there was any better ways to do the operation other than this

Comment: Others have pointed out the same flaws I was going to point out, too.

Answer (score 1):

> can this piece of code be used to delete a node at a specified position

This is the correct algorithm for the most part. It doesn't handle deletion of position 0 correctly through so it cannot be used as such.

> what is the most efficient method to delete a node in a specific position?

More efficient than this is to pass pointer to previous node as argument instead of pointer to head and position. But for given inputs, the algorithm that you've used is asymptotically optimal.